# Count Divisors of Product from L to R

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math

I have been solving a problem but then got stuck upon its subpart which is as follows:

> Given an array of N elements whose ith element is A[i] and we are given Q queries of the type [L,R].
>
> For each query output the number of divisors of product from Lth element to Rth element.
>
> More formally, for each query lets define P as P = A[L] * A[L+1] * A[L+2] * ...* A[R].
>
> Output the number of divisors of P modulo 998244353.
>
> Constraints : 1<= N,Q <= 100000, 1<= A[i] <= 1000000.

My Approach,

For each index i, I have defined a map< int, int > which stores the prime divisor and its count in the product up to [1, i].

I am extracting the prime divisors of a number in O(LogN) using Sieve.

Then for each query (lets say {L,R} ), I am iterating through the map of Lth element and subtracting the count of each each key from the map of Rth element.

And then I am answering the query using the result:
if N = a^p * b^q * c^r ...(a,b,c being primes)
the number of divisors = (p+1)*(q+1)*(r+1)..

The time complexity of above solution is O(N*D + Q*D), where D = number of distinct prime numbers upto 1000000. In worst case D = 78498.

Is there more efficient solution than this?

Comment: We only have prime divisors of `N` until `sqrt(N)`. Also, the law of exponents state that if `N = 2^a * 3^b * 5^c * ...`, then `N` will have `(a+1) * (b+1) * (c+1) * ...` divisors. I'm pretty sure this will be helpful.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for responding, I am finding the prime divisors of N using sieve in O(logN)  and also I am making use of the above formula you stated to calculate the number of divisors.

Comment: you can try this: creating a matrix M, where `M[i][j] = how many primes i we have from 0 to j`, where i is the i-th prime number. For example: `M[2][5] = 8` means we have 8 occurrences of 3 (that is the 2-nd prime number) from index 0 to index 5.
With this, you can do any query in `sqrt(N)` time (hence `O(Q*sqrt(N))`) just subtracting the indices in R from the indices in L and multiplying.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for responding, but I am not able to understand how the query will be answered in sqrt(N) because for calculating the divisors we would have to go through each i in M[i][R] - M[i][L] and the number of such i's will be D=78498. So the again it will be O(Q*D) time.

Also one more concern that creating such matrix could lead to memory limit exceeded because of size 78498*100000.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more efficient solution for this.  But it is slightly complicated.  Here are steps to get to the necessary data structure.

1. Define a data type `prime_factor` that is a struct that contains a prime and a count.
2. Define a data type `prime_factorization` that is a vector of the first data type in ascending size of the primes.  This can store the factorization of a number.
3. Write a function that takes a number, and turns its prime factorization into a `prime_factorization`
4. Write a function that takes 2 `prime_factorization` vectors and merges them into the factorization of the product of the two.
5. For each number in your array, compute its prime factorization.  That gets stored in an array.
6. For each pair in your array, compute the prime factorization of the product.  We will only need half of them.  So elements `0, 1` go into one factorization, `2, 3` into the next and so on.
7. Repeat step 6 `O(log(N))` times.  So you have a vector of the factorization of each number, pairs, fours, eights, and so on.  This results in approximately `2N` precomputed factorization vectors.  Most vectors are small though a few can be up to `O(D)` in size (where `D` is the number of distinct primes).  Most of the merges should be very, very fast.

And now you have all of your data prepared.  It can't take more than `O(log(N))` times the space that storing the prime factors required by itself.  (Less than that normally, though, because repeats among the small primes get gathered together in one `prime_factor`.)

Any range is the union of at most `O(log(N))` of these computed vectors.  For example the range `10..25` can be broken up into `10..11, 12..15, 16..24, 25`.  Arrange these intervals from smallest to largest and merge them.  Then compute your answer from the result.

An exact analysis is complicated.  But I assure you that query time is bounded above by `O(Q * D * log(N))` and normally is much less than that.

**UPDATE**:

How do you find those intervals?

The answer is that you need to identify the number divisible by the highest power of 2 in the range, and then fill out both sides from there.  And you figure that out by dividing by 2 (rounding down) until the range is of length 1. Then multiply the top boundary by 2 to find that mid-point.

For example if your range was `35-53` you would start by dividing by 2 to get `35-53`, `17-26`, `8-13`, `4-6`, `2-3`.  That was `2^4` we divided by.  our power of 2 mid-point is `3*2^4 = 48`.  Our intervals above that midpoint are then `48-52, 53-53`.  Our intervals below are `40-47, 36-39, 35-35`.  And each of them is of length a power of 2 and starts at a number divisible by that power of 2.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice approach. I can understand the basic hindsight in your approach which is to divide the range in the powers of 2( which would be atmost LogN) and then merging the answers for each range quite similiar to as we do in sparse table. Thanks again!

Comment: I was having one doubt, wont we have to take each consecutive pair in step 6, like [0,1] , [1,2], [2,3] .... and so on and similiarly for next powers of two, because while breaking the range [L,R] into powers to two, there might come a situation where we might need [1,2] whose precomputed prime_factorisation would not be available according to step 6 ?

Comment: @SanyamAgarwal No.  You can always identify the number divisible by the highest power of 2 in the range, and then you need `log(N)` intervals on power of 2 boundaries to fill out each side.  Additional intervals might have been convenient to have, but are never needed.

Comment: @SanyamAgarwal I added an explanation of how to always find those intervals.

Comment: Yes i agree that it will always be possible to form the range from 2N intervals but how would we know which intervals to take. For example if range is [0,2] then after breaking and arranging range from smaller to larger we have [0],[1,2], but here we don't have precomputed available prime_factorization of [1,2], whereas if we would have taken intervals as [0,1], [2] then it would have been possible. It would depend upon the order of intervals

Comment: sadly this approach didnt work. I guess there test cases are such that the elements of array are primes that repeat in a cyclic fashion which would always guarantee the worst case scenario while quering